# how to add legend to ggplot barplot with individual colours for each bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot, so hopefully this is an easy question. I've made a stacked barplot with colours for each segment given in col:

```
a <- data.frame(var = rep(seq(1:2),2), val = seq(1:4))
col <- c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'red')

ggplot(a, aes(x = var, y = val)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = col)
```

which looks like this:

[image]

how do I add a legend to the plot? I tried

```
+ scale_fill_manual(name = 'legend', breaks = seq(1:4), values = col)
```

Comment: Also note you can use `geom_col` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close!

Move `fill = col` to `aes`:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.frame(var = rep(seq(1:2),2), val = seq(1:4))
col <- rainbow(n = 4)
ggplot(a, aes(x = var, y = val, fill = col)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    scale_fill_manual(values = col)
```

You have to put it within `aes` as `col` is variable that you want to map to specific aesthetic (in this case `fill`).

Comment: Thank @PoGibas. Sorry, may question wasn't clear enough. I edited it. Hopefully it is clearer now